# How can I do addSpeech() in TTS of Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I write simple program for tts. I want to study tts function. My code is below.

```
    String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
    String destFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/hello.wav";
    mTts.addSpeech(wakeUpText, destFileName);
    mTts.speak(wakeUpText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

you can see the code is very like http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

My problem is that if the hello.wav is not exist, tts cannot speak.

error log is below

```
DEBUG/MediaPlayer(398): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

...

```
DEBUG/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use just it:

```
String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
mTts.speak(wakeUpText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Not use:

```
String destFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/hello.wav";
mTts.addSpeech(wakeUpText, destFileName);
```

You have error message **DEBUG/MediaPlayer(398): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1** becouse you don't have the file